# Force C to stop interpreting newlines differrent from CR LF

Tags: c, mingw

My program read a Windows text file line by line, using `fgets` with `MinGW`.
Each line is ended by `CR LF` (`'\r'`, `'\n'`).
The text file is generated by tools and sometimes contains the character `'\n'` in the data.

I found out that `fgets` ignores every character after the `'\n'` and part of my data is missing.

How to change this behavior, so that:

- Single `'\n'` are treated as a normal character
- `'\r' '\n'` is treated as new line

Edit:
I found out that some double-quoted strings in my file do have `'\n'` in the data, but also do have `'\r' '\n'` in the data somtimes. Unfortunately, I cannot fix the tools. So I had to write some code, as suggested in the valuable comments.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. I suggest you write your own `fgets`. But anyway on Windows text files are not supposed to contain single \n s,

Comment: You could read (using `fread`) into an internal buffer inside your program, and then parse out the lines yourself. But remember to open the file in binary mode, otherwise you won't be able to see the carriage-return (as on Windows the library will translate `\r\n` into `\n` for files opened in text mode).

Comment: `fgets` _stops reading_ upon encountering `\n`, but it doesn't discard anything.

Comment: I found this [fgets](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/64b8a48e1288eb3902ed73113d157af50b2ec596/lib/libc/stdio/fgets.c) implementation but looks not trivial. Do you guys have any link to share? You are correct Lundin, fgets does not discard anything, it just does not provide the rest of the line.

Comment: Another simple solution is to just read one character at a time in a loop. When you see a `'\r'` followed by a `'\n'` you have a newline and can process it.

Comment: @Robert ideally those tools shouldn't generate text output containing isolated \n s. If you have no control over these tools the simplest thing is to write your own `fgets` that exhibits the behaviour you described using the method described in the previous comment. Use `fgetc` to read one char at a time. I estimate the size of a simple rewritten `fgets` function to less than 15 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I posted here the code I wrote to fix the issue.
The code is probably buggy, posted below as reference:

```
static void DIRTY_ReadLine (FILE     *File,
                            uint8_t  *Buffer,
                            uint32_t  BufferSizeInBytes)
{
  uint8_t  *pChar = Buffer;
  uint32_t  ByteCount;
  int32_t   Character;
  int32_t   PreviousCharacter;
  bool      NewLineFound;
  bool      InsideString;

  Character         = fgetc(File);
  PreviousCharacter = 0;
  NewLineFound      = false;
  InsideString      = false;
  ByteCount         = 0;

  while (!NewLineFound
         && (Character != EOF)
         && (ByteCount < BufferSizeInBytes))
  {
    if (!InsideString
        && (PreviousCharacter == '\r')
        && (Character == '\n'))
    {
      pChar--;
      *pChar       = '\0';
      NewLineFound = true;
    }
    else
    {
      if (Character == '\"')
      {
        InsideString = !InsideString;
      }      
      *pChar            = (uint8_t)Character;
      PreviousCharacter = (uint8_t)Character;
      pChar++;
      ByteCount++;
      Character = fgetc(File);
    }
  }
}
```